# Select solution in CRM 2013 gives error A error has occurred please return to the home page

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have created a new solution and when i goto add existing entities as shown in the below figure it throws the below error " A error has occurred please return to the home page."

[image]

Comment: are you using Google Chrome V37? did you try with Internet Explorer?

Comment: @GuidoPreite worked. Damn was breaking my head. Please add this as answer would like to give credit to you thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is present only with Google Chrome. Starting from Google Chrome V37 the API *showModalDialog* is deprecated (it's used heavily inside Dynamics CRM).

More details here: [The (browser compatibility) cake is a lie](http://www.crmanswers.net/2014/09/the-browser-compatibility-cake-is-lie.html)

A registry fix is available: [Google Chrome registry fix for Dynamics CRM 2011/2013](http://www.crmanswers.net/2014/09/google-chrome-registry-fix-for-dynamics.html)

It if doesn't work it's necessary to apply the patch by a policy: [Chrome 37 breaks CRM 2011 functionality](http://xrmrocks.com/2014/09/08/chrome-37-breaks-crm-2011-functionality/)

Google Chrome 38 broke another part of Dynamics CRM, the lookups.

Details here: [Lookup errors with Google Chrome 38](http://www.crmanswers.net/2014/10/lookup-errors-with-google-chrome-38.html)

And a fix using a managed solution (unsupported) here: [Google Chrome 38 Lookup Fix](http://www.crmanswers.net/2014/10/google-chrome-38-lookup-fix.html)

Comment: Thanks marked it its more detail as compared to @Bluesam thanks

Answer (score 0):

As @GuidoPreite said, this is a Google Chrome issue. Several of the customization functions have issues in Google Chrome, but this is probably the biggest issue with Chrome.